# how to move div to other place when viewing on mobile device

Tags: css

i have a div #friend_sites on sidebar

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="friend_sites">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="somesite.com">Site 1</a></li>
           ....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And footer:

```
<div id="footer">
    Copyright text
</div>
```

I want when user viewing on mobie device, div #friend_site move to footer. currently, i use 2 same div, then show/hide it, on desktop browser, i hide div on footer and show div on sidebar. On mobile browser, i hide div on sidebar and show div on footer.

But it seems so stupid, i want to clean up my html code, what is the correct way to make this using css?

Comment: Use media query and change the position of div by css on specific width (compatible with mobile device)

Comment: You can use bootstrap for responsive web designs

Comment: Here is this new cool thing in css now css grid layout. Using it you can have a single html but display it in multiple ways. That ways you can have a single footer div and it can go anywhere you want in any view.

Comment: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example13/ check this out

Comment: Use flexbox or grid order property

Comment: @omukiguy is there any sample code of grid order in this case, thanks in advance

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/YPzyYa Could show you a trick. However, your issue is unique seeing you might be having a lot of content in the sidebar and might not be using flexbox or grid through out. Can you share a little more of your markup?

Comment: @BùivănNguyện I think it's better to have to same div and hide one on desktop

Comment: thanks all, i solve problem by follow @omukiguy 's solution

Comment: Please share your answer below